# Tab completion in script

Tags: ruby, tabs

I'm trying to implement a cli script with ruby which can tab complete valid commands.  I have a script which performs a number of tasks.  I would like to roll this into a cli in which the user could tab complete commands.  Is there a gem out there?  If not, how might I roll my own?  As simple as process std input and handle TAB?  The only prob I see with that is how to see the tab when Enter Key has not been pressed.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Thank you,

hk

For example:

```
cli> show [enter]
show version
show system state
show interface rate


cli> show interface [enter]
show interface rate
show interface state
show interface channel-groups

cli> show inter [tab]
cli> show interface chann [tab]
cli> show interface channel-groups
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not going to be able to do this with standard io.  I would recommend ncurses, perhaps [ncurses-ruby](http://ncurses-ruby.berlios.de/).